# Sending Emails With Large File Attachments from .net web application

Tags: .net, email-attachments

Is there a best practice solution to the problem of sending an email message directly from a asp.net web application that has large file attachments? Whether using smtp or an api service like mailgun or sendgrid, the problem is the same - slow.

Is the only way to create a background service (e.g. a windows service) to send these emails from a datatbase queue or similar?

I'd like to know how others have tackled this problem. Thanks for any advice in this regard.

Comment: Its slow because of regular bandwidth problems not because of the protocol. not much you can do..

Comment: ok thanks - so the only solution is to do back-ground processing then?